# Python Bleak library start_notify not permitted - Not paired

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to a BLE heart rate monitor using a Raspberry Pi model 2B using the standard Raspian Pi OS (recently updated) and a Bluetooth BLE dongle.

I try to connect and pair first and only then try to start_notify

```
async def main(address, uuid):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        
         try:
             await client.connect()
             print(f"Connected: {connected}")
         except Exception as e:
                     print(f"Failed to connect: {e}")
        
         if client.is_connected:
             try:
                 paired = await client.pair()
                 if paired:
                     print(f'Pairing successful')
                 else:
                     print("Pairing failed")
             except Exception as e:
                 print(f"Failed to pair {e}")
        
        await client.start_notify(uuid, notification_handler)
        
        print("Subscribed to heart rate notifications. Press Ctrl+C to exit")
        
        await ayncio.sleep(30)
        
        await client.stop_notify(uuid)
        
        await client.disconnect()
```

It tells me that the connection fails because it is already connected, then it tells me it has paired. Then the error tells me that I am not paired, how can that be?

I've tried removing both the code that does the pairing and connection and still i get the same error. I checked I am connecting to the correct device with a BLe Scanner device on my phone and if I connect to the device from the app then I can't connect to it through the code, signalling that it is the correct device.

```
Failed to connect: Client is already connected
Pairing successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/oxa_breath_band/main.py", line 80, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main(address, uuid))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "oxa_breath_band/main.py", line 38, in main
    await client.start_notify(uuid, notification_handler)
  File "Oxa_Breath/oxa_breath_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 834, in start_notify
    await self._backend.start_notify(characteristic, wrapped_callback, **kwargs)
  File "Documents/Oxa_Breath/oxa_breath_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.py", line 958, in start_notify
    assert_reply(reply)
  File "Documents/Oxa_Breath/oxa_breath_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/utils.py", line 22, in assert_reply
    raise BleakDBusError(reply.error_name, reply.body)
bleak.exc.BleakDBusError: [org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted] Not paired
```

I am using the latest version of the Bleak library (0.21.1) but did also try using version 0.14.0 based off a online recommendation. Bluetoothd/bluetoothctl version = 5.55. Python 3.9